# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row - I get this error even though I use SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a query that selects all the drivers that were fined in the same place where another driver was fined.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.IdSofer), s.NumeSofer
FROM Soferi s
INNER JOIN contraventii c ON c.IdSofer= s.IdSofer
HAVING (SELECT DISTINCT IdLocContr FROM Contraventii c 
INNER JOIN Soferi s ON c.IdSofer=s.IdSofer
INNER JOIN Localitati l ON s.IdLocSofer=l.IdLoc
WHERE s.NumeSofer='Maneta Gheorghe' AND l.DenLoc='Pocreaca' AND l.Jud='IS' GROUP BY IdLocContr) = c.IdLocContr
GROUP BY s.NumeSofer, c.IdLocContr, c.IdSofer;
```

This is what I tried but I get the error message

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

If I run only only the SELECT statement between parentheses it works fine. It shows the id of cities (two cities) where this driver was fined. But if I try to run the code as I wrote here I get this error.

[image]

### EDIT

This is the SQL from my comment...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.IdSofer)
      ,s.NumeSofer
  FROM Soferi s INNER JOIN contraventii c
    ON c.IdSofer= s.IdSofer
 GROUP BY s.NumeSofer
         ,c.IdLocContr
         ,c.IdSofer
HAVING (SELECT DISTINCT IdLocContr
          FROM Contraventii c INNER JOIN Soferi s
            ON c.IdSofer=s.IdSofer INNER JOIN Localitati l
                                           ON s.IdLocSofer=l.IdLoc
         WHERE s.NumeSofer = 'Maneta Gheorghe'
           AND l.DenLoc = 'Pocreaca'
           AND l.Jud = 'IS'
      GROUP BY IdLocContr) = c.IdLocContr
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: In a SQL query, the `HAVING` clause must follow a `GROUP BY`. In the SQL you posted, `HAVING` appears before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have put a photo with the extras from DB where are shown only the fines from the cities where the driver was finned. The output has to be the driver name "s.NumeSofer"

Comment: That should be a correlated subquery in the `where` clause I suspect. Definitely not a typical `having`.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(c.IdSofer), s.NumeSofer
FROM Soferi s
INNER JOIN contraventii c ON c.IdSofer= s.IdSofer
GROUP BY s.NumeSofer, c.IdLocContr, c.IdSofer
HAVING (SELECT DISTINCT IdLocContr FROM Contraventii c 
INNER JOIN Soferi s ON c.IdSofer=s.IdSofer
INNER JOIN Localitati l ON s.IdLocSofer=l.IdLoc
WHERE s.NumeSofer='Maneta Gheorghe' AND l.DenLoc='Pocreaca' AND l.Jud='IS' GROUP BY IdLocContr)= c.IdLocContr
;

Comment: I did this and I get the same error.

Comment: @shawnt00 I don't think I know what it means.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **NOT**  a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Putting parentheses around one column won't change anything for that. `select distinct (a),b` is the same as `select distinct a,(b)` or `select distinct a,b`

Comment: DISTINCT does not ensure you only get a single row - it only makes sure you don't get duplicate values

Comment: I removed the parantheses. Still get this error.

Comment: Probably a good idea to learn SQL syntax before writing complicated query.

Comment: What can I do to get only a single row?

Comment: @Eric I'm trying to learn now but I am at my first steps on complicated queries. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE c.IdLocContr IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT IdLocContr
    FROM Contraventii c 
        INNER JOIN Soferi s ON c.IdSofer=s.IdSofer
        INNER JOIN Localitati l ON s.IdLocSofer=l.IdLoc
    WHERE s.NumeSofer = 'Maneta Gheorghe' AND l.DenLoc = 'Pocreaca' AND l.Jud = 'IS'
)
```

Just a few notes for your benefit.

The `distinct` isn't really necessary inside an `in` subquery although I left it there. Also you were using both `distinct` and `group by` which were redundant for that query. `Having` comes into play when you want to filter based on group aggregates.

Comment: If this solved your problem you have a responsibility to accept the answer by clicking on the little check mark under the upvote/downvote totals for the answer. This will turn it green, indicating that the answer has been accepted, and will award the poster 15 points. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's too long to put in comment, so I put it here.  Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you checked whether the query below returns one row or not?  If not, then that's what you have to fix.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IdLocContr 
FROM Contraventii c 
INNER JOIN Soferi s ON c.IdSofer=s.IdSofer
INNER JOIN Localitati l ON s.IdLocSofer=l.IdLoc
WHERE s.NumeSofer='Maneta Gheorghe' AND l.DenLoc='Pocreaca' AND l.Jud='IS' 
GROUP BY IdLocContr
```

From the look at it, I doubt it will only return 1 row.

Comment: It returns two rows. One for every city where the driver was finned.

Comment: @BeginerUser Then there's your problem.

Comment: But it has to. Because the driver was finned in two different cities, with two different id. As I said, this SELECT statement worked just fine. The problem was (as shawnt00 pointed in his solution) that I was using HAVING clause instead WHERE value IN. I have also tried with WHERE, but I was using = instead of IN and that was the problem.

Comment: But, the put equality in the query, so there can't be more than 1 value.  You'll need to change your query if you want to support multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

your having clause should return one value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IdLocContr
          FROM Contraventii c INNER JOIN Soferi s
            ON c.IdSofer=s.IdSofer INNER JOIN Localitati l
                                           ON s.IdLocSofer=l.IdLoc
         WHERE s.NumeSofer = 'Maneta Gheorghe'
           AND l.DenLoc = 'Pocreaca'
           AND l.Jud = 'IS'
           AND rownum<=1
      GROUP BY IdLocContr
```